# Why didn't Deadpool just have his friends remove the collar?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

At the end of *Deadpool 2*, Deadpool is wearing the collar from the prison that makes him lose his Mutant power. It seems to prevent his regeneration.

That collar is easily removed. It removes itself when Cable comes after Deadpool's fall. Cable has to reverse time to ensure that Deadpool isn't dead. That's complicated.

**Why not just remove the collar?**

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being closed as unclear, but hopefully the edits I made will prevent the last vote. It should be obvious to anyone who saw the movie what you're asking.

Comment: @laurel sorry didn't see your edit, feel free to rollback

Comment: The big metal guy, colossus, can easily  yank the collar out of deadpool without hurting his neck. Even if Colosus hurts deadpool's neck, so what? Deadpool will survive.

Answer (score 12):

### Because Wade asked them not to

After Deadpool jumps in front of the gunshot and gets hit they start trying to remove his collar but he stops them from doing it.

> **Deadpool:** Stop, stop, stop! Stop! Just let it happen, okay?
>
> <sub>*Deadpool 2*</sub>

After he actually dies and he can no longer stop them from helping him Cable forces his hand and saves him.

Answer (score 0):

He purposely put it on himself so that he wouldn’t have his powers and could now be killed like a normal person. He sacrificed himself to save Russell (Firefist) and show him that someone actually does care about him and he doesn’t need to kill the headmaster or anyone else and thus does not go down the dark path his future self had, leading him to murder Cable’s family. Also, he was ready to finally die so he could be reunited with Vanessa.

Comment: Making people feel bad for asking questions isn't nice.

Comment: I don’t think that was entirely fair to edit, you removed part of the answer that was actually relevant to the question. I apologize if I offended anyone or hurt someone’s feelings.

Comment: Given that the answer essentially duplicates what's already been answered, I wasn't overly fussed about preserving the quality. Note my delete vote